# Purge logs older than 3 months in NCover Code Central

Tags: logging, ncover, purge

I am using NCover Code Central (3rd party tool) for code coverage. This is deployed in a server with 2 partitions. NCover is deployed in C drive and C drive has around 100GB capacity. But now, the drive is reaching its capacity. Upon some investigation, we found that the logs of NCover are taking around 75GB. Is there a way to gracefully purge the logs from NCover UI and also have a setting to not retain the logs after 3 months? Please help. I couldn't find much information in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use the "Ncover compact" command line option to compact logs on disk. You can also use "Ncover archive" command to archive old data to zip files that can be moved elsewhere.